# AVPlayer plays HLS but crashes with MP4 video

Tags: avplayer, ios10, avplayerviewcontroller, imasdk

AVPlayers plays HLS but crashes with MP4 video. I am using the following URLs; I am also using IMA SDK for iOS to play ads, which works perfectly with the 1st URL, but the app crashes with the 2nd one without playing the ad.

using iOS version: 10.1

```
//NSString *const kTestAppContentUrl_MP4 = @"http://50.7.149.90:1935/pitvlive/ptvsportsnew3.stream/playlist.m3u8";

NSString *const kTestAppContentUrl_MP4 = @"http://50.7.149.74/vods/trailers/OK Jaanu-Official Trailer.mp4";


> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid number value (NaN) in JSON write'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076b634b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010aba621e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010771f265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010a6efbfe _writeJSONNumber + 302
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010a69a138 _writeJSONValue + 480
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010a6efa12 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke + 226
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107646e55 __65-[__NSDictionaryI enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 85
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107646d6a -[__NSDictionaryI enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 250
    8   Foundation                          0x000000010a6ef806 _writeJSONObject + 430
    9   Foundation                          0x000000010a69a0dd _writeJSONValue + 389
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010a6efa12 ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke + 226
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010763d9d6 __65-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 102
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010763d8da -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 202
    13  Foundation                          0x000000010a6ef806 _writeJSONObject + 430
    14  Foundation                          0x000000010a69a0dd _writeJSONValue + 389
    15  Foundation                          0x000000010a699f04 -[_NSJSONWriter dataWithRootObject:options:error:] + 124
    16  Foundation                          0x000000010a699de4 +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 333
    17  AVPlayer                            0x0000000106c552e4 -[IMAJavascriptDispatcher sendMessage:] + 313
    18  AVPlayer                            0x0000000106c55c5e -[IMAJavascriptSession sendMessage:] + 135
    19  AVPlayer                            0x0000000106c5f40d -[IMABaseManager sendMessage:data:] + 161
    20  AVPlayer                            0x0000000106c5dd1c -[IMABaseManager initializeWithAdsRenderingSettings:] + 1295
    21  AVPlayer                            0x0000000106c5d7f7 -[IMABaseManager initializeWithContentPlayhead:adsRenderingSettings:] + 100
    22  AVPlayer                            0x0000000106c5b336 -[IMAAdsManager initializeWithAdsRenderingSettings:] + 108
    23  AVPlayer                            0x0000000106c5173b -[ViewController adsLoader:adsLoadedWithData:] + 331
    24  AVPlayer                            0x0000000106c59e3f __39-[IMAAdsLoader handleMessageAdsLoaded:]_block_invoke + 94
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d3a9980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d3d30cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d3b38d6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010767a4f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010763ff8d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010763f494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ce2ca6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    32  UIKit                               0x0000000108778964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    33  AVPlayer                            0x0000000106c5215f main + 111
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d41f68d start + 1
    35  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What happens if you play the standalone MP4 in AVPlayer? I'd recommend trying other MP4s as well.

Answer (score 0):

There was a space in the URL, so i used the following method from someone to encode the URL.

```
- (NSString *) URLEncodedString_ch:(NSString*) str {
NSMutableString * output = [NSMutableString string];
const unsigned char * source = (const unsigned char *)[str UTF8String];
int sourceLen = strlen((const char *)source);
for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
    const unsigned char thisChar = source[i];
    if (thisChar == ' '){
        [output appendString:@"+"];
    } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' ||
               (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
               (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
               (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
        [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
    } else {
        [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
    }
}
return output;
```

}